# Determine all units in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega] := \{a+b\omega\mid a,b\in\mathbf{Z}\}$ where $\omega = \frac{-1 + i \sqrt{3}}{2}$

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Determine all units in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega] := \{a+b\omega\mid a,b\in\mathbf{Z}\}$ where $\omega = \frac{-1 + i \sqrt{3}}{2}$

**My Attempt:**

$N(a + b\omega) = (a + b \omega)(a - b \omega) = a^2 + \omega^2 b^2$

I'm stuck here. Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The norm is the product of the conjugates, in the sense of algebraic extensions. The conjugate of $\omega$ is the other root of its minimal polynomial $x^2 + x + 1$ – it's $\omega^2$. So $$N(a + b \omega) = a^2 - ab + b^2.$$

Now to have $N(a + b \omega) = 1$, either $a = 0$, so we obtain $\pm \omega$ as units. Or $a \ne 0$, and we can write $a^2 - ab + b^2 = a^2(1 - x + x^2)$, where $x = \frac b a$.

As $1 - x + x^2\ge \frac 34$, we can have $a^2 - ab + b^2 = 1$ only if $a^2 = 1$.

If $a = 1$, $a^2 - ab + b^2 = 1 - b + b^2 = 1 \iff b = 0$ or $b = 1$.

Similarly, if $a = -1$, we find $b = 0$ or $b = -1$.

At the  end, we find the units are $\pm 1, \pm \omega, \pm \omega^2$. It's a cyclic group, generated by $-\omega$ or $-\omega^2$.

Comment: You gave same answer as I did.

Comment: Actually no, I am wrong, you spoke about algebraic extensions when there's not need to, and moreover, you never justified why being a unit implies having norm equal to $1$.

Comment: I supposed it was part of the basic things known to the O.P. since he/she wrote about units in a ring of integers. For the norm, I just recalled its definition.All this stuff is intricately mixed.

Comment: Ah ok, let's admit it. But then, you give the same solution as I do, isn't it ? ;-)

Comment: I certainly wouldn't give other units than the known ones. Actually I ended writing my solution while you were posting yours, and I give other details of computation.  But if you think it's too close, I'll withdraw my answer.

Comment: Here $w$ is an undefined symbol, but it's clear to me that you meant the $\omega$ defined in the question header.

Comment: FWIW, I think this answer could use a bit of cleanup, but it's a fair bit clearer than the other one, and closer to what OP is likely to want.  (Algebraic extensions are almost certainly relevant to the question at hand, given that it's a question _about_ an algebraic extension!)

Comment: @Robert Soupe:  I think originally the O.P. used $w$, or I misread. Normally, I use $\omega$.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, that didn't occur to me, even though I noticed both the question and your answer had been edited before I got to them.

Comment: what is the connection between the unit of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and the prime elements of it?

Answer (score 2):

No, your second equality is wrong. See this :

I note $A := \mathbf{Z}[\omega] := \{a+b\omega\;|a,b\in\mathbf{Z}\}$ where $\omega = \frac{-1 + i \sqrt{3}}{2}$. Consider $N : A \to \mathbf{N}$ defined by $N(z) := z\overline{z}$ for all $z\in A$, where $\overline{z}$ denote $z$'s complex conjugate. This definition shows that $N$ is multiplicative, as complex conjugation is multiplicative. Now let $z$ be a unit in $A$, so that we have a $z'$ in $A$ such that $zz' =1$. Then $N(zz') = N(1)=1$, but $N(zz') = N(z)N(z')$ as $N$ is multiplicative. So that $N(z)N(z') = 1$. But $N$ takes values in $\mathbf{N}$, so there is not choice : $N(z) = 1$. If you write $z = a+b\omega$ with $a,b\in\mathbf{Z}$, this is equivalent to say that $a^2 + ab(\omega + \overline{\omega}) + b^2 |\omega|^2 = 1$, that is, to $a^2 - ab + b^2 = 1$, with $a,b\in\mathbf{Z}$. Knowing this equation, what can you say now about $a$ and $b$ ?