# Associates in rings that differ by more than sign

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Are there any rings where associates differ by more than just sign (e.g., 1 or -1)?

So far everything I've learned either involved associates differing by sign or a constant multiple, but I'm curious if there are other cases where the associates differ by more. I can't think of any...

Comment: What is "constant multiple" supposed to mean in a general ring?  Are you stuck thinking in terms of $R[x]$?  Associates *are* multiples by something...

Comment: Take your favorite domain $D$ then pick a nonzero nonunit $d$ and force $d$ to be a unit by adjoing its inverse to obtain $D[1/d]$. Here  $ad^j$ and $ad^k$ are associate since they differ by a unit multiple (some power of $d$) E.g. in $\Bbb Z[1/2]$ we have that $3$ is associate to $3\cdot 2^k\  $ (essentially this ignores the prime $2$). Complementarily we can invert all primes but $2$ and then  all odds are units.

Comment: @rschwieb yes, i was referring to polynomial rings differing by a constant multiple

Comment: @Gone excellent general example. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an example, take your favorite ring $R$ with $R^\times$ something else than $\{\pm 1\}$. For example $R=\mathbf{Z}[i]$, then $\mathbf{Z}[i]^\times=\{ \pm 1,\pm i\}$ so in there $3+2i$ and $2-3i$ are associate!

Comment: thank you, i see what youre saying. by the way, what does $R^\times$ refer to?

Comment: $R^{\times}$ is the group of invertible elements in your ring $R$.

Answer (score 1):

Elements $a,b\in R$ in an integral domain are called *associated* if we have $b=au$ for a *unit* $u\in R^{\times}$. So your question is equivalent to the question for which domains the units group is different from $\{\pm 1\}$.

Examples are the certain rings of integers in number fields, such as
$$
\Bbb Z[\omega]^{\times}=\{\pm 1,\pm \omega,\pm \omega^2\}
$$
where $\omega$ is a primitive third root of unity.

Reference: [Determine all units in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega] := \{a+b\omega\mid a,b\in\mathbf{Z}\}$ where $\omega = \frac{-1 + i \sqrt{3}}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126638/determine-all-units-in-mathbbz-omega-ab-omega-mid-a-b-in-mathbfz)

Comment: No, that definition only works in domains.

Comment: Yes, I have edited, thank you.